# Reactive send file to web service in Play!2 Scala

Tags: web-services, scala, playframework-2.0

I've got a file in a Play!2 app that I want to send to a web service call.  I want a reactive way to read the file and send it.  I want something like the following:

```
val source = Source.fromFile("/path/to/someFile")
val holder: WSRequestHolder = WS.url("http://example.com/service")
val futureResult = holder.post(source)
futureResult.onComplete({source.close()})
```

But the above code does not compile.

Is there an idiomatic way to reactively stream a file to a web service?

Comment: What's the compiler error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found out that this is, in fact, very easy with Play's build in web services:

```
WS.url("http://http://example.com/service/").post(new io.File("path/to/someFile"))
```

That is, the `post` function can take a `File` option, and, presumably, streams correctly.